# How to connect two tables in oracle 10g database?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table named `REGISTRATION` with fields like `ID, NAME, PASSWORD, USERNAME`.
I want to make another table named `PHOTOS` with fields `ID, TITLE, PHOTO`. 
The thing I want to ask is that I want the `ID` field of the `PHOTOS` table should match with the `ID` field of the `REGISTRATION` table. 
Whenever there is any entry in the `REGISTRATION` table the content of `ID` field gets copied into the `ID` field of `PHOTOS` table....??

Comment: Looks like an `UPDATE` with `JOIN`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: That does not sound like a good DB design. Why not just add the photo columns into your other table and call it `users`?

Comment: @juergend What if this application is designed to manage several photos (as the table name PHOTOS indicates) for each user?

Comment: According to the description - not. He wants the same ID for the photo and user.

Comment: @juergend Yes, it is the same user. There would be only one registration entry, but several photos. It does make sense to me if he want to insert a default photo when the user gets created. The user might be able to add more photos to his/her profile later. Of course, all these are my assumptions.

Comment: By learning this concept i can relate many other tables with the first table where in all other table the id field is generated automatically. i tried using foreign key references but it didn't work.

Comment: @JosephB : so according to you i have to initialize all the tables first?

Comment: @RagingBull: how to do it..?

Comment: @dheeraj The logic is up to you. I imagined that when a new user gets registered, you would insert a row in the REGISTRATIONS table. At the same time, you will also insert a new row in the PHOTOS table. The ID will be the same. The TITLE and PHOTO may be NULL if the user has not selected a photo yet or otherwise, they could be populated with the data selected.

Comment: @JosephB: yes you are right i will do the initializations at the  time of registration.. and then i can easily update photos and other fields..

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one photo per user, then yes, it is a good idea to make ID the same. But then why it is not just one table that contains info from registration and photos?

if you have multiply photos per user, then no.
ID usually recognized as unique identifier of a record in a table (2 records in the same table have different IDs). So instead of using ID for user, you use UserId as an additional column in PHOTOS table.